# Nativescript: Dynamic listview showing only one row

Tags: listview, nativescript

Can anyone help me with this issue? The listview is showing only one row.

Is there a way to show all the items in the listview?

**XML View**

```
<ScrollView>
    <stack-layout id="stackID">

    </stack-layout>
</ScrollView>
```

**Code Behind**

```
var listViewModule = require("ui/list-view");
var layout = page.getViewById("stackID");

var listView = new listViewModule.ListView(); 
var colors = ["red", "green", "blue"];
listView.items = colors;

layout.addChild(listView);
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

1. Unless you have to; don't put a ListView inside a ScrollView.   ListViews have their own scrollview code built in.
2. If you HAVE to put a ListView into the ScrollView, you need to set the Height of the ListView to make everything work properly.  (It is also recommended you set the size of the ScrollView in this case also).

You layout should be

```
<Page><StackLayout> ....  other views ....
<StackLayout id="stackID">
  <!-- ListView dynamically inserted here -->
</StackLayout>
</StackLayout></Page>
```

Comment: Nathanael , Hi. But there are cases where I can't compute the overall height since of dynamic text from db. For example [looking here](https://i.imgur.com/zgr9vRP.jpg) - I put the red zone in scrollview , and the blue zone needs to be `ListView` , so how would you that ? ( worth to mention that the page is long as you see. As far as I can see , the only solution is to use `*ngfor` for the blue zone... What do you say ? What is your recommendation  here ?

Comment: If you think you are going to get multiple comments (i.e. more than 3) then a ListView should work; but you want to make sure you give the listview a height of approx the three comments.    You might still have to intercept some events from the scrollview and foward them to the listview...